# Read json content from remote and printing on main interface in Xcode with swift 5

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode

I got an error while reading json content from remote url and printing on main interface in iOS Simulator.

MBP13"2016 && Mojave 10.14.6 && xcode 10.3(10G8) && swift 5

Here is the code sample. I had change a bit from "https://www.simplifiedios.net/swift-json-tutorial/"

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    //the json file url
    let URL_POSTS = "https://demo.ghost.io/ghost/api/v2/content/posts/?key=22444f78447824223cefc48062";

    //A string array to save all the names
    var nameArray = [String]()

    //the label we create
    @IBOutlet weak var labelTest: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        //calling the function that will fetch the json
        getJsonFromUrl();
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    //this function is fetching the json from URL
    func getJsonFromUrl(){
        //creating a NSURL
        let url = NSURL(string: URL_POSTS)

        //fetching the data from the url
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (url as URL?)!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in

            if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary {

                //printing the json in console
                print(jsonObj.value(forKey: "posts")!)

                //getting the companies tag array from json and converting it to NSArray
                if let heroeArray = jsonObj.value(forKey: "posts") as? NSArray {
                    //looping through all the elements
                    for heroe in heroeArray{

                        //converting the element to a dictionary
                        if let heroeDict = heroe as? NSDictionary {

                            //getting the name from the dictionary
                            if let name = heroeDict.value(forKey: "name") {

                                //adding the name to the array
                                self.nameArray.append((name as? String)!)
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }

                OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
                    //calling another function after fetching the json
                    //it will show the names to label
                    self.showNames()
                })
            }
        }).resume()
    }

    func showNames(){
        //looing through all the elements of the array
        for name in nameArray{

            //appending the names to label
            labelTest.text = labelTest.text! + name + "\n";
        }
    }        
  }
```

From the result above, it seems ok that I had found content result in console while fetching json from remote url , but nothing shows up on main interface with iOS simulator.

[json result in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgAa4.png)

[main interface nothing show up in IOS Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMwtW.png)

Answer (score -1):

I've had some kind of this problem with JSON keys and NSDictionary usage. What worked out for me was just using **Decodable** protocol. I would recommend using this new API for parsing instead of JSONSerialization.

Here's a few good reads:

https://medium.com/swiftly-swift/swift-4-decodable-beyond-the-basics-990cc48b7375
https://medium.com/xcblog/painless-json-parsing-with-swift-codable-2c0beaeb21c1